# Problem with controlling playback speed in C# using the NAudio library

Tags: c#, naudio, playback, trackbar

I am trying to use the following code to control the playback speed of an audio object with NAudio library but am running into some problem.
How can I alter the play back speed of the media playing object without running into exceptions and bugs, Thanks in advance.

```
using NAudio.Wave;
using NAudio.Wave.SampleProviders;
 namespace \_2
 {
 
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       private WaveOutEvent outputDevice;
       private AudioFileReader audioFile;
       private VarispeedSampleProvider speedControl;
       public Form1()
      {
           InitializeComponent();
      }

       private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
           outputDevice?.Dispose();
            audioFile?.Dispose();
         }

         private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
             if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                txtFilePath.Text = openFileDialog.FileName;
            }
         }
 
       private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
          if (outputDevice == null)
            {
                outputDevice = new WaveOutEvent();
               outputDevice.PlaybackStopped += OnPlaybackStopped;
             }
            if (audioFile == null)
           {
                 audioFile = new AudioFileReader(txtFilePath.Text);               outputDevice.Init(audioFile);
           }            outputDevice.Play();        }
       private void OnPlaybackStopped(object sender, StoppedEventArgs args)
        {
            outputDevice.Dispose();             outputDevice = null;
            audioFile.Dispose();
           audioFile = null;
        }
       private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            outputDevice?.Stop();
       }

       private void TrackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)        {
           if (speedControl != null)
           {
            speedControl.PlaybackRate = trackBar1.Value / 10f;
            }
       }
   }
     
 }
```

Comment: Hello, I wrote a sample program in C# to play an audio file and be able to increase or decrease the playback speed using a trackbar. I used the following code but it gives an error that I am unable to solve. If possible, could someone help me to fix this code for adjusting the speed? Thank you.   I have also installed the latest version of the NAudio library.

Comment: If your comment is supposed to be additional information/detail for your question, then edit and add to the question, do not use comment section.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not show how you are calling `Init` on your `outputDevice`. But the `AudioFileReader` needs to be passed into the `VarispeedSampleProvider` and then that needs to be passed into `Init`.